# Syntax error in shell code

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, syntax-error

I am a beginner in shell scripting.
Can anyone please tell me, what is the error in this code?

```
#!usr/bin/sh
#palindrome
echo "enter the number"
read a

len = ` echo $a | wc -c `
while [ $len -ne 0 ]
do
a1 = ` echo $a | cut -c $len `
rev = ${rev}${a1}
len = ` expr $len - 1 `
done
if [ $a == $rev ]
then 
echo " palindrome"
else
echo "not a palindrome"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Try running your code through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) first to get the most basic issues out of the way, then update your code with what you're left with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!usr/bin/sh # <-- This is probably not where `sh` is. You need the absolute path.
             #     sh is /bin/sh on many systems

#palindrome
echo "enter the number"
read a

len = ` echo $a | wc -c ` # <-- shell doesn't allow whitespace around assignments
                          #     Do len=`echo $a | wc -c`
while [ $len -ne 0 ]
do
a1 = ` echo $a | cut -c $len `
rev = ${rev}${a1}
len = ` expr $len - 1 `
done
if [ $a == $rev ] # <-- use a single `=` sign.
then 
echo " palindrome"
else
echo "not a palindrome"
fi
```

That's it for the functional issues. You may also consider:

1. Use `"${#a}"` to get the number of characters in the parameter `a`.
2. Use `"${a: $x:$y}"` to get a substring of the expansion of `a`.
3. Use `$()` instead of backticks for command substitution. It nests better.
4. Use `read -p` instead of `echo …; read`.